# libobjc.A.dylib crash in Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

I am getting this weird crash in Crashlytics and i dont understand what might be the problen. My app gets information from the network and saves in core data. Its also uses some location functionalities.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is correctly symbolicated? Since stack trace is not clear itself

Comment: Can you replicate the crash, or it's only happening to your users?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure the main thread is the one that crashed in this instance. Are you sure you don't have more info about where the crash occurs in some of the other threads that were running too?

Comment: Its only happening to users. No i dont have any other info. It happened to 45 users in an app with over 8.000 downloads.

Comment: There was [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910902/magic-of-nsoperation-internals-how-does-it-observe-isfinished-key-so-that-comp) about `__NSOperationInternal`'s method. Maybe it helps?

Comment: Post the code of your AppDelegate.swift (around line 15) ...

Comment: @FormigaNinja That's obviously the generated main method.

Comment: Please add the whole crash log - the important steps are missing (1, 7-13).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess would be to take a look @ the code where you're registering / de-registering for location change notifications & review against an example. (This idea is mainly prompted by the reference to key / value observation)

Comment: i'm wondering how you figured out this is related to CLLocation use? I'm facing same crash reports by crashlytics as well

Comment: This is just a bit of experience & intuition talking. Of the technologies Christos described, location is the only one that has a heavy key-observer use (which you can see referenced in the crash report).

Answer (score 0):

In general, I found useful to check "More details..." - if you're also tracking screen views, at least you'll be able to check on which screen the app crashes.